# Generate all permutations with sort constraint

Tags: python, list, combinatorics

I have a list consisting of other lists and some zeroes, for example:

```
x = [[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0, 0, 0]
```

I would like to generate all the combinations of this list while keeping the order of the inner lists unchanged, so

```
[[1, 1, 2], 0, 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0]
```

is fine, but

```
[[1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0, 0, [1, 1, 2], 0]
```

isn't. I've got the feeling that this should be fairly easy in Python, but I just don't see it. Could somebody help me out?

Comment: More general version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944987/all-the-ways-to-intersperse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 2.6,

```
import itertools

def intersperse(x, numzeroes):
    for indices in itertools.combinations(range(len(x) + numzeroes), numzeroes):
        y = x[:]
        for i in indices:
            y.insert(0, i)
        yield y

x = [[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]]
list(intersperse(x, 3))
```

Comment: This won't give all possiblities. It will give only 4 results for the given example, when there should be 20.

Comment: ah, right. should have been + numzeroes not + 1.  Fixed now, len(list(intersperse(x, 3))) = 20.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :) y.insert(0, i) should be y.insert(i, 0), but otherwise it works great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

One hint:  If there are z zeros and t lists then the number of combinations you describe is [choose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)(z+t, z).  (The [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(probability)) trick will help to see why that's true.)

To generate those combinations, you could generate all the length-z subsets of {1,...,z+t}.
Each of those would give the positions of the zeros.

Even better, here's a generalization of your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944987/all-the-ways-to-intersperse

Your input x can be converted into a form y suitable for the above generalization as follows:

```
x = [[1,1,2], [1,1,1,2], [1,1,2], 0, 0, 0]
lists = [i for i in x if i != 0]
zeros = [i for i in x if i == 0]
y = [lists, zeros]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like...:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = [[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0, 0, 0]
>>> numzeros = x.count(0)
>>> listlen = len(x)
>>> where0s = itertools.combinations(range(listlen), numzeros)
>>> nonzeros = [y for y in x if y != 0]
>>> for w in where0s:
...   result = [0] * listlen
...   picker = iter(nonzeros)
...   for i in range(listlen):
...     if i not in w:
...       result[i] = next(picker)
...   print result
... 
[0, 0, 0, [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]]
[0, 0, [1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]]
[0, 0, [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 2]]
[0, 0, [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0]
[0, [1, 1, 2], 0, 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]]
[0, [1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 2]]
[0, [1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0]
[0, [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, 0, [1, 1, 2]]
[0, [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 2], 0]
[0, [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0, 0]
[[1, 1, 2], 0, 0, 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]]
[[1, 1, 2], 0, 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 2]]
[[1, 1, 2], 0, 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0]
[[1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, 0, [1, 1, 2]]
[[1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 2], 0]
[[1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0, 0]
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, 0, 0, [1, 1, 2]]
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, 0, [1, 1, 2], 0]
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], 0, [1, 1, 2], 0, 0]
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Can be micro-optimized in many ways, of course, but I hope the general idea is clear: identify all the set of indices that could have zeros, and put the non-zero items of the original list in the other places in order.